# reading seq_file from kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Could you post some examples how to read list of meanings from */proc* files?

```
list_head* get_from_proc_file()
{
   struct file* file = fopen("example","r");
   seq_open(file, &seq_ops);
   struct seq_file *p = file->private_data;
   READ LIST OF DATA?????
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `fopen` as this is a libc function. The example bellow shows how to read a file from the kernel.

http://www.wasm.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=467952#p467952

Comment: It is not likely, but possible that /proc is not mounted. In that case reading file from /proc will not work. In addition to that, /proc exports information that is already available in-kernel, so it seems wrong to read it as file anyway

Comment: I need virtual file in /proc for my own kernel module. So this solution works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't need to read a /proc file within kernel, because a /proc interface is used by kernel to export some information to user-space, the information definitely already exists in kernel, either in some list of struct's or other global containers. So the proper way is probably just getting the global list/container by calling some kernel API or using them directly, if they are exported.